# Flutter assests_audio_player import doesn't work

Tags: flutter, audio-player

My flutter has suddenly started giving me this error on assets_audio_player : "Undefined class 'AssetsAudioPlayer'.". The import for the player: **import 'package:assets_audio_player/assets_audio_player.dart';** is also greyed out. I've tried upgrading the flutter & restarting the device but the issue is still there. Any clue what might've gone wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Please share more insights. Like the code with the import and the where it is actually used.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you're using [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/assets_audio_player/install).
Be sure to add a line like this to your package's *pubspec.yaml* (and run an implicit `flutter pub get`).

```
dependencies:
  assets_audio_player: ^3.0.4+1
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I already added the dependency. I figured out that it required i need to update my application to Android embedding v2 to solve this.

Comment: Alright Noor, did this fix your issue in the end?

Comment: yes, after upgrading to  Android embedding v2 and setting minsdk to 31, it was resolved.

Comment: Nice one, Noor!

Answer (score 1):

Before importing the package in your code, did you properly add its dependency in your "pubspec.yaml" file and then run the `flutter pub get` command?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I already added the dependency. I figured out that it required i need to update my application to Android embedding v2 to solve this.